# Cannot get access to pandas DataFrame in the way expected

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a strange dataframe, that doesn't seem to operate in the way I expect. I should have a column heading that I can use.

The code I have produces the following, which is supposed to be used for a histogram.

```
categories = pd.Series(df['category'])
category_freq = pd.Series(df[df['engine'] == 'u']['category'])
hist = pd.crosstab(category_freq, categories)
counts = pd.DataFrame(np.diag(hist), index=[hist.index])
```

But the output has a `'0'` at the very top. I cannot seem to get things behaving as I would want. For example the output looks like the following:

```
0
category    
baby        65    
beauty      73
christmas   168
```

If I access via `counts[0]`, I can remove this "top layer", but I can never find a way to access rows via say `counts[0]['category']`. I get key not found. How can I get the data in a format that works as DataFrame?

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what's going on without a reproducible example, but probably use just need to use a `Series` instead of a `DataFrame`.

Comment: Did you try: `counts[(0, 'category')]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a `Series` out of it instead:

```
counts = pd.Series(np.diag(hist), index=[hist.index])
```